# I want to reload the same page when add button is clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a page where i can add the category details and after clicking the plus button i want to add the category into a list and should reload the same page again how to do that using a floating action button?

```
FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => {
        AddNewItemNext(),

      },
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
```

Comment: did you tried `setState` in `onPressed` callback?

Comment: Yep to add the items to the list I used **setState**

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `StatefulWidget` and `setState`.

Here you append the new data to the list.

```
FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => {
        setState(() {
          list.add(data);      
        });
      },
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.